# Different texts in UILabel remain the same font size in UICollectionView Cells

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

For instance,

1. I have 4 itemsInSection from UICollectionView, they have same height and width based on device size.
2. For the UILabel inside of cell, make it equal width and height with multiplier 1:3 of cell. I want UILabel size grow or shrink when screen size changed.
3. Texts in UILabel for each cell are different, such as "Pen", "Documents", "Lee" and "Beats"
4. I set fontSize = 22pt, minimumScaleFactor is 0.5 and adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is true
5. But the problem is "Documents" will be the smallest font size, all other text font looks much bigger than it.

**Question**: How can I make all UILabel text size same as the longest text one and same time the font size should shrink or grow based on screen size?

Eg. iPhone 8 Plus font size should be bigger than iPhone SE font size, because we have more room on iPhone 8 Plus.

[image: iPhone SE screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can check which label has the largest number of characters using:

```
label.text.count
```

once you know which is the longest, you can just use a simple extension like:

```
extension UILabel{
    func anchorFontSize(toLabel: UILabel) {            
        let text: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: toLabel.attributedText!)
        text.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: toLabel.font], range: NSMakeRange(0, text.length))
        let context: NSStringDrawingContext = NSStringDrawingContext()
        context.minimumScaleFactor = toLabel.minimumScaleFactor
        text.boundingRect(with: toLabel.frame.size, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: context)
        let adjustedFontSize: CGFloat = toLabel.font.pointSize * context.actualScaleFactor
        let font = self.font.fontName
        self.font = UIFont(name: font, size: adjustedFontSize)            
    }
}
```

to anchor the font sizes of the other labels to the font size of the longest label.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It was my bad not describe clearly. According to your answer, it will always return minimum font for the longest word. From my example, when  the screen is bigger (iPhone 8 plus) the font will always be 17pt. Please take a look my updated description again. Thanks

Comment: Nope. In this case the change will be dynamic depending of the font size of the longest word and the minimum scale factor. For example: if in iphone SE the minimum scaled size to fit the label is 15 pt all of them will end up of 15 pt. If you now have more room and the minimum scaled size is 17 pt, all of them will end up of 17 pt. This extension does not give you the minimum size but the minimum scaled size to fit.